# Soft keyboard capital initially

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want that when a user taps on a `TextBox` the keyboard should be capital initially and then small case after entering first character.

I have seen this in calendar app.
When you tap on `Add title` the shift key is initially on and when you tap on `Add a message` it's off
Here are the screen shots..

Screen shot #1

[image]

Screen shot #2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick summary of the different `InputScope` types you can set for the on-screen keyboad.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx

It sounds like `"Text"` worked for you, but `"Chat"` will also begin with a capital. The difference is that `"Chat"` does not auto-correct.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this. In WP 8, it's done by defining InputScope to text:

```
<TextBox x:Name="DescriptionTextBox" InputScope="Text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attached behavior](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.hk/2012/03/attached-behaviors-for-windows-8-metro.html) with your text block control which listen to key pressed events, which can then accordingly convert the character casing as you desire.

Comment: No I don't want to force user to put first character as capital. It just looks good to have by default capital keyboard initially. The same as in Calender App when you create a new event initially keyboard is caps then caps is off.

Comment: no you are not forcing user with attached behavior, when user inputs something you take that character, and change it ascii + 128

Comment: it is forcing.. what if user wants to input first letter as small?