# Where do I start with XAML?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am wanting to learn XAML (especially for Windows 8) where would be a good place to start?

Tutorials? Samples? White papers? Best practices? Tips and tricks?

What helped you learn?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your May 22 2012 blog post seems to suggest you're already expert in XAML or at least reasonably proficient. Yet here you are asking for "how to learn" tips. Serious question: are these posts just shilling for WinRT development? Trying to pad out the post count with these tags? I know this place is a hotbed of gaming the system but it strikes me as just sleazy.  http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/windows-8-why-i-choose-xaml-metro-over.html

Comment: @BobRiemersma He is a MS guy and I have seen many MS guys active on stack and It's good for window-8 developer. He has asked this question so that other can have benefits for it.

Comment: @Jerry there are other question related to windows-8 please try to answer that too. Here is one http://stackoverflow.com/q/13472075/468724

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Thank you for enlightening me.  It never occurrred to me that posing hypothetical questions and answering them under an alias (or by playing off other "clan" members) was a legitimate mode of participation.  However I have now found numerous instances of it and I recognize that the format here doesn't provide any other mechanism to open up a discussion topic instead of only asking real questions.

Comment: @BobRiemersma No, I speak to hundreds and hundreds of developers every month. And, when one question keeps coming up over and over I think it is worth asking on StackOverflow - I assume there are even more developers who would ask me the same thing if they could; I am asking this question on their behalf. And, to be honest, esp. with this particular question, I don't have a good "go-to" answer. My XAML skills came up organically. I didn't keep a journal of how I learned. And I want to have a rock solid answer for them. I am not gaming anything. Not even a little, buddy. Give me a break.

Answer (score 2):

I learn best by doing, so the very best resource for me was the Contoso Cookbook hands-on labs.  They walk through all of the new Windows 8 features for developers and give you experience coding for each.  You can download them from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29854).  Choose the Win8CS.Setup.exe download for C# and XAML (the Win8JS.Setup.exe download is JavaScript and HTML).  The labs include:
1.ListViews/GridViews and Data Binding
2.Orientation, Snapping, and Semantic Zoom
3.Searching and Sharing
4.Appbars and Media Capture
5.Lifetime Management
6.Settings and Preferences
7.Tiles and Notifications
8.Windows Store

Answer (score 1):

There is a book called Programming Windows 8 by Charlez Petzold that is pretty good. Not very advanced but great for beginners. It is not published your but there is a "beta" version available on O'Reilley...

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145369079.do

Comment: I have the book myself. Excellent.